# ORA 00933: SQL command not properly ended with C#

Tags: c#, oracle

My SQL statement is

```sql
delete from d1 
where ID in 
(select d1.ID 
from d1 
join d2 
on d1.d2ID = d2.ID 
where d2.xxx = '...');
```

Use Navicat to connect to oracle database, execute the sql statement `successfully`.

But when using `Oracle.DataAccess` or `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` to execute the sql statement, an error is reported:

```
ORA 00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Later, I found that: just remove the last `semicolon`, and it runs successfully.

But this makes me very confused, I want to know the difference between removing the semicolon and not removing the semicolon.

My Oracle version is 12, and the version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccessd is 19.10.0 (the latest version).

That would be great if someone answers this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually semi colon represent the end of the statement in oracle.

When querying from any application which accepts the sql statement, you do not need to end the statement explicitly. It is taken care via specific application or it is not needed if only one statement need to be executed.

So you should not use semi colon in any application which accepts the query as a string. (Same behaviour you will be able to find in oracle using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` which accepts one sql statement without semi colon)

Hope, It is clear to you now.